# Qml OpacityMask reduces image quality

Tags: image, qml, opacitymask

I have a Rectangle that contains an Image.
I'm trying to create a rounded image with a black border.
I've tried using an OpacityMask, but when I do, it reduces the image quality.
Also there is a very small amount of white space in some places between the border and the image.
I've provided the code below. The commented out lines are things I've tried to no avail. I've also tried making the Rectangle and Image siblings contained within an Item with a separate sibling OpacityMask but get the same result.

Does anyone know a better way of doing this.
Also does anyone know a better way of creating the border - at the moment I'm stopping the image covering the border by using

```
anchors.margins: imageRect.border.width
```

[image]  [image]

```
Rectangle {
     id: imageRect
     property int spacer: 10 
     property int spacedWidth: imageDel.width - spacer
     anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
     width: spacedWidth
     height: spacedWidth / imageListModel.getImageWToHRatio()  
     border.color: "black"
     border.width: 2
     radius: imageRadius
     //clip: true

     Image {
        id: image
        source: "image://lmImageProvider/" + rowIndex + "_" + index
        //sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: imageRect.border.width
        cache: false
        //visible: false
        //fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        layer.enabled: true
        layer.smooth: true
        //layer.textureSize: "600x900"
        layer.effect: OpacityMask {
           maskSource: imageRect
           // cached: true
        }
        //mipmap: true


        property bool reload: reloadImageRole
        onReloadChanged: {
           source = ""
           source = "image://lmImageProvider/" + rowIndex + "_" + index
        }

        MouseArea {
           anchors.fill: parent
           onClicked: {
              imageListModel.toggleSelected(rowIndex + "_" + index)
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why the above code doesn't work. 
Also not sure why my original attempt at "making the Rectangle and Image siblings contained within an Item with a separate sibling OpacityMask" (which was based on another answer in Stack Overflow), didn't work.
But upon much further investigation, I found another answer which was a slight variation on the "making the Rectangle and Image siblings contained within an Item with a separate sibling OpacityMask" which did work. Updated code is below:

```
Rectangle {
   id: imageRect
   property int spacer: 10 
   property int spacedWidth: imageDel.width - spacer
   anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
   width: spacedWidth
   height: spacedWidth / imageListModel.getImageWToHRatio()  
   border.color: "black"
   border.width: indImageBorderWidth
   radius: indImageRadius

   Image {
      id: image
      source: "image://lmImageProvider/" + rowIndex + "_" + index
      anchors.fill: parent
      anchors.margins: imageRect.border.width - 2
      cache: false
      visible: false

      property bool reload: reloadImageRole
      onReloadChanged: {
         source = ""
         source = "image://lmImageProvider/" + rowIndex + "_" + index
      }
   }

   Rectangle{
      id: maskRect
      anchors.fill: image
      radius: indImageRadius - 3
      visible: false
      z: image.z + 1
   }

   OpacityMask {
      anchors.fill: image
      source: image
      maskSource: maskRect
   }
   MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked: {
      //imageListModel.toggleSelected(rowIndex + "_" + index)
      console.log("Image Clicked: " + rowIndex + "_" + index)
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, the issue is things will go wrong if the image contents being referenced in effects "loop". In this case Your opacity mask was referring to the Rectangle which contained the item that had that effect on it so it becomes self-referential and visually things begin to break when that happens.